# Largest infinite cardinal used in a proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, cardinals, infinity

I've heard before that Knuth holds the record for the largest constant used in a mathematical proof.

I was wondering what is the largest cardinal ever explicitly considered in set theory. I presume this will depend on the axioms chosen, but I'd be interested to know what's the 'largest infinity conceived by man'.

Comment: There are numbers beside cardinals you would want to look into. Surreals have both the biggest and smallest imaginable.

Comment: I wonder why the negative votes. If this question is based in a misconception I am happy to learn from it, but please do point out why asking it would be inappropriate.

Comment: @FelipeJacob : I upvoted the question, not to compensate, because we're not supposed to do that, but because I liked the question.

Comment: @PyRulez The ordinals sit inside the class of Surreals in a natural way, and given any Surreal, there is an ordinal larger than it. Therefore, while I appreciate the chance to bring up the Surreals, they don't buy you anything here that the concept of cardinals doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, for some reasons.

For example, in many consistency proofs in set theory one begins by taking some very very very large cardinal $\kappa$. This is not only an assumption which tells us that the cardinality of $\kappa$ is ineffable and beyond our wildest imagination; it also means that assuming that such cardinal exists is a far stronger assumption than just the axioms of $\sf ZFC$.

One recent work I've been doing with a classmate/colleague (we have the same advisor) begins with a Mahlo cardinal above a supercompact cardinal. While Mahlo are not "that large" of a large cardinal, supercompacts are, and so this Mahlo cardinal is quite big. But you can just as well begin with a Mahlo cardinal which is larger than an infinite number of supercompact cardinals, which is an even larger cardinal. And you can keep pushing this sort of limit, on and on and on. Of course, one of the aims is to be minimal in the assumptions, but this sort of "pushing up" is naturally occurring in set theory (as is "pushing down" the consistency bounds and attempting to find minimal assumptions).

So in a kinda of copping out, I'll say that the largest infinity conceived is the universe of set theory. That is an infinity so large we cannot even assign it a cardinal number. It is larger than all the other infinities, by definition. And within the bounds of a fixed universe, one cannot possibly exceed it in any way.

Of course, this depends on what universe of set theory you're in, and whether or not you prescribe to a multiverse approach, or you're a Platonist, or so on.

Comment: The von-neumann universe is a proper class. Of course then we can make something even "bigger:" the category of all classes, and then the conglomerate of all cateogries and so on ad superinfinitum.

Comment: Karl, the point is that we can't. If we are in a fixed universe of set theory, we cannot talk about the "category of all classes". For doing so we need a larger universe of set theory, which we commonly assumes to exist (see the Tarski-Grothendieck set theory with universes, sine you mention categories). But once you have fixed **the universe**, you cannot go beyond its limits with just first-order logic.

Comment: I realize now that I ended up asking two questions. The second one may very well be answered by your 'cope out'. However, we could also double Knuth's constant to get something larger. The point is that number was explicitly used in a proof. Is there a largest cardinal explicitly considered to prove something? Does κ also fit that role?

Comment: @Felipe: That depends on what do you mean by "explicitly". The cardinal $\beth_{\omega_1}$ was used in a proof, but $\sf ZFC$ has no means to decide whether or not this is $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ or something much much larger. Moreover being an inaccessible cardinal means that you cannot be described in any non-vacuous way, $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa=\beth_\kappa$, and so on. So we cannot refer to it explicitly, but yet we do refer explicitly to inaccessible, supercompact and huge cardinals in proofs.